# Unfixable mixed-revision working copy in SVN

Tags: svn, merge, svn-externals

I have a branch checkout that is clean (no modifications), but I cannot reintegrate the trunk back into my branch, because SVN thinks I have a mixed-revision working copy:

```
c:\myproject> svnversion
2045:2047
```

The problem seems to be caused by one of my externals:

```
c:\myproject> svn propget svn:externals tools
-r1448 ^/tools/external/trunk/gandalf/bin gandalf/bin
-r1508 ^/tools/external/trunk/gandalf/include gandalf/include
-r1508 ^/tools/external/trunk/gandalf/lib gandalf/lib
-r1428 ^/tools/external/trunk/jsdb jsdb
-r2045 ^/tools/external/trunk/java/lib/jing.jar jing.jar
```

You will note that all of them are directory externals rather than single-file externals, except for jing.jar, which is the same version as what "svnversion" thinks is the lowest range of my working copy, which is supposed to be a clean checkout of r2047.

How do I fix this (besides not using the single-file external)?

I've tried doing updates, fresh checkouts, and svn cleanup, and it still has this problem. I'm using TortoiseSVN 1.6.12

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Looks like you're not the only one with this problem.

The fix is to use the equivalent of `svn update --ignore-externals`

See here:
[Reintegrate a branch with externals fails in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764002/svn-reintegrate-a-branch-with-externals-fails/1823018#1823018)

Comment: Thanks, run `svn update` simply worked for me

Answer (score 7):

I came to a different solution, `--allow-mixed-revisions`:

```
svn merge -c7777 https://repo/app/branches/1.0 . --allow-mixed-revisions
```

Ignoring externals when updating didn't fix the problem for me even if I did a completely fresh checkout.

Answer (score 2):

Note that this issue has been fixed since Subversion 1.7.0. Since then [`svnversion`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnversion.re.html) (and the merge logic) ignore file externals when determining the revisions.

Comment: I actually have the very same problem with svn 1.8.11.

Answer (score 1):

Even immediately after updating/pushing my entire repository, I got this error message just for trying to rename a folder. Updating the folder again right before renaming fixed this issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, my FIX relates to [Best answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5112819/912046) (but I used `switch` command instead of `update` with *no externals*).

I describe how to fix it with Eclipse subversion.

[image]

Error in console

```
merge --dry-run --depth=infinity --force --ignore-ancestry -r133880:133881 svn+ssh://{svnPath} {localPath}
    svn: E195020: Cannot merge into mixed-revision working copy [133 963:133 967]; try updating first
    svn: E195020: Cannot merge into mixed-revision working copy [133 963:133 967]; try updating first
    Dry-run merge completed abnormally.
```

I first refreshed (Team > Switch) my local branch with **Ignore externals** option

[image]

Output in console:

```
switch svn+ssh://{svnPath} {localPath} -r HEAD --depth=infinity --ignore-externals --force
```

Then, the merge or its dry run were successful.

```
merge --dry-run --depth=infinity -r133880:133881 svn+ssh://{svnPath} {localPath}
Dry-run merge complete.
    ===== File Statistics: =====
    Updated: 5
```

Complete before/after output in console:

```
merge --depth=infinity -r133956:133957 svn+ssh://{svnPath} {localPath}
    svn: E195020: Cannot merge into mixed-revision working copy [133 970:133 971]; try updating first
    svn: E195020: Cannot merge into mixed-revision working copy [133 970:133 971]; try updating first
    Merge completed abnormally.
switch svn+ssh://{svnPath} {localPath} -r HEAD --ignore-externals --force
    At revision 133971.
merge --depth=infinity -r133956:133957 svn+ssh://{svnPath} {localPath}
    --- Merging r133956 through r133957 into {localPath}
    U   {localPath}/index.html
    Merge info recorded for {localPath}
    Merge complete.
    ===== File Statistics: =====
    Updated: 1
    ==== Property Statistics: =====
    Updated: 1
```

Inspired by:

- (current best answser) https://stackoverflow.com/a/5112819/912046
- [Ignore a svn:"property" while doing svn merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148069/ignore-a-svnproperty-while-doing-svn-merge)
- [Reintegrate a branch with externals fails in SVN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1764002/reintegrate-a-branch-with-externals-fails-in-svn/1823018)