# Ignore a svn:"property" while doing svn merge

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I have a svn:external property in my trunk project.
From that trunk I have a branch coming out that has a svn:external to a different path.
The branch is constant. That means I don't want to close it a i'm continually working on it.

When changes have been made in the branch I want to merge them back into the trunk.
The thing is, I want all the changes EXCEPT the svn:external property.

When I try to merge, I don't get a conflict because svn is too smart and does update on the property. If I had a conflict I could use mine always.

I thought about using a svn hook to revert that specific change but I want to use that as a last resort.

Any other ideas?
Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use the option `--record-only` once after changing the `svn:externals` on the branch to mark the revision as already merged without actually merging it.

```
# changing svn:externals on branch
svn propedit svn:externals branches/foo/externals
svn commit

# mark commit as already merged 
svn merge -c rev --record-only branches/foo trunk
svn commit
```

Comment: I tried using the `--record-only` option but when I did reintegrate merge (using tortoise-svn) the svn merged this revision too.

Comment: I am confused. First you said that the branch is "constant", i.e. it will not be closed. Now you are saying that you get merge conflicts during reintegration, i.e. branch closing. Do you merge changes from branch to trunk and later reintegrate the branch with the trunk?

Comment: I'm just performing a reintegration merge so that all of the revisions will be merged back to the trunk. I don't want or have to close it by using a reintegration merge.
I thought about merging the specific revisions I need every time I want to, but since i'm in a team and we have a lot of revision I fear some revision might not be merged by accident (human mistakes).

Comment: _Merging all of the revisions_ is called a _Sync Merge_. A _Reintegrate Merge_ is something completely different. Apparently you are using Subversion not the way it is meant to be used. That makes it difficult to give a correct answer. However, using sync merges instead of reintegrate merges should at least solve this particular problem.